# Anyone know why my Component Keeps Remounting?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why does my component keep remounting it just keeps alerting success which means it is in a infinite loop

I took the dependancies out of the use effect and it stopped so i guess one of the dependancies keeps changing? Please help?  Let me know if you need more information about the component or want to view my context file with all of my data in it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      var parts = props.location.pathname.split('/');
      var lastSegment = parts.pop() || parts.pop();
      console.log('DOM is loaded');
      console.log(lastSegment);
      let searchNumber = Number(lastSegment);
      // If items have been Set
      if (trending.length > 1) {
        handleDetail(searchNumber);
        alert('success');
      }

      (async () => {
        await domLoaded;
        // alert('domLoaded');
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (trending.length > 1) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        }, 200);
      })();

      var category = detailProduct.category;
      youMightLike(category);

      setTimeout(() => {
        setyouMightLikeItem(
          //Random Item
          youMightAlsoLike[Math.floor(Math.random() * youMightAlsoLike.length)]
        );
        console.log(youMightAlsoLike);
      }, 300);

      if (category !== 'love') {
        switch (category.toLowerCase()) {
          case 'mens fashion':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-male');
            break;

          case 'mens shoes':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-shoe-prints');
            break;

          case 'womens fashion':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-female');
            break;

          case 'gadgets':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-brain');
            break;

          case 'phone accessories':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-mobile-alt');
            break;
          case 'pc':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-laptop');
            break;

          case 'water pipes':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fab fa-angellist');
            break;
          case 'smoke accessories':
            setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-cannabis');
            break;

          default:
            alert('Fiya');
            break;
        }
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (category.toLowerCase().includes('mens')) {
          setChoice('/mens');
        } else if (category.toLowerCase().includes('womens')) {
          setChoice('/womens');
        } else if (category.toLowerCase().includes('phone')) {
          setChoice('/phoneAccessories');
        } else if (category.toLowerCase().includes('pc')) {
          setChoice('/pc');
        } else if (category.toLowerCase().includes('water')) {
          setChoice('/waterpipes');
        } else if (category.toLowerCase().includes('smoke accessories')) {
          setChoice('/smokeaccessories');
        } else if (category.toLowerCase().includes('smoke shop')) {
          setChoice('/smoke');
        } else {
          setChoice('/searchProducts');
        }
      }, 300);
    }, [detailProduct.category, handleDetail, props.location.pathname, trending.length, youMightAlsoLike, youMightLike]);
```

Comment: Do you know that your `useEffect` similar to `componentDidUpDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to Move My button with all the logic to a different component as the answer above stated

```
    import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
    import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
    import { ProductContext } from '../context';
    const domLoaded = require('dom-loaded');
    const RecomendedItem = props => {
      const [youMightLikeItem, setyouMightLikeItem] = useState([]);
      const [youMightlikeImg, setyouMightlikeImg] = useState(null);
      const productConsumer = useContext(ProductContext);
      const {
        detailProduct,

        youMightAlsoLike,

        youMightLike
      } = productConsumer;
      const { category } = detailProduct;
      let id = Number(props.match.params.id);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (1) {
          youMightLike(category);
          console.log(youMightAlsoLike, 'You Might Also Like');

          if (category !== 'love') {
            switch (category.toLowerCase()) {
              case 'mens fashion':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-male');
                break;

              case 'mens shoes':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-shoe-prints');
                break;

              case 'womens fashion':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-female');
                break;

              case 'gadgets':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-brain');
                break;

              case 'phone accessories':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-mobile-alt');
                break;
              case 'pc':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-laptop');
                break;

              case 'water pipes':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fab fa-angellist');
                break;
              case 'smoke accessories':
                setyouMightlikeImg('fas fa-cannabis');
                break;

              default:
                alert('Fiya');
                break;
            }
          }
        } // eslint-disable-next-line
      }, [category, youMightAlsoLike.length, id]);
      // !category, youMightAlsoLike.length, id
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to={`/details/${youMightAlsoLike.id}`}>
            <button className="like">
              You might also like <i className={youMightlikeImg}></i>
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default withRouter(RecomendedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're watching WAY too many changes for useEffect. Every time any one of those things changes, useEffect is run and the component re-renders. You should break apart your logic so that non-dependent states are separated in to separate useEffects(). In addition, if you're looking for something to run just once, you can put an empty array at the end of the useEffect.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of breaking the logic down and what nondependant state it? All of the logic in the useffect changes?

Comment: I need this to rerender when the url changes but its not working